# Django 'manage.py test' failing to migrate models to test database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unit-testing, django-models

I am having trouble running unit tests with Django.

According to the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#using-different-testing-frameworks

The default Django testing behavior involves:

1. Performing global pre-test setup.
2. Looking for tests in any file below the current directory whose name matches the pattern test*.py.
3. Creating the test databases.
4. Running migrate to install models and initial data into the test databases.
5. Running the system checks.
6. Running the tests that were found.
7. Destroying the test databases.
8. Performing global post-test teardown.

Anytime I try to run

```
./manage.py test
```

Django gets as far as step 3, creating the test database, then throws an error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "accounts_user" does not exist
```

It seems it is failing to migrate my models to the test database. Since it crashes it doesn't remove the test database. I can psql into the test database and see that it exists but it is empty. This behavior occurs even if I don't have any tests written out.

I don't know if this is the culprit but I do have a custom user model defined as follows

```
def user_image_path(instance, filename):
    '''
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to
    '''
    first_name = instance.first_name.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    last_name = instance.last_name.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    cleaned_filename = filename.lower().replace(" ", "_")

    return '{0}_{1}/images/avatar/{2}'.format(first_name, last_name, cleaned_filename)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, username=None, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a valid email address")

        if not first_name and last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a first and last name")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            password=password,
        )

        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True

        user.save()

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    '''
    '''
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=user_image_path)

    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    YOUR_STATE_CHOICES = list(STATE_CHOICES)
    YOUR_STATE_CHOICES.insert(0, ('', '---------'))
    state = USStateField(blank=True, null=True, choices=YOUR_STATE_CHOICES)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)

    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    email_user = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name',]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} @{}, {}".format(self.email, self.last_name, self.first_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

    def email_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
        send_mail(
            '{}'.format(args[0]),
            '{}'.format(args[1]),
            'support@example.com',
            [self.email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

I also have django-registration installed and several models that use

```
models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm not sure if the custom user model or the ForeignKey references are whats causing it to flip or not, but the custom user model is the only thing that's in any way unusual about my app wrt 'stock' Django behavior.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

P.S. I'm working with Django 2.0.1. Postgresql. macOS 10.13.2.

dependency list is as follows

```
appdirs==1.4.3
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
boto3==1.5.18
botocore==1.8.32
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
confusable-homoglyphs==2.0.2
coverage==4.4.2
Django==2.0.1
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-bootstrap4==0.0.5
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-extensions==1.9.9
django-localflavor==2.0
django-registration==2.3
django-storages==1.6.5
djangorestframework==3.7.7
docutils==0.14
idna==2.6
jmespath==0.9.3
lxml==4.1.1
olefile==0.44
packaging==16.8
Pillow==5.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.3
requests==2.18.4
s3transfer==0.1.12
six==1.11.0
stripe==1.77.1
typing==3.6.2
urllib3==1.22
```

Comment: It looks like the "accounts_user" table was not created. Are you using a custom user model? If so, it can be a little finicky to get working. There are some flags you have to set so Django's default ORM behavior doesn't mess things up. Please post your models.py.

Comment: I did post my models.py... I cannot seem to find any reference in the docs to the flags you mention.

Comment: These are the flags I have in my custom user: 

    `class Meta:
        managed = False # Ensure Django doesn't "manage" the table
        db_table = 'users' # Point to actual DB table`

Are you letting Django manage your users table?

Comment: Yes, Django is managing users table. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How is it receiving a ProgrammingError for the table not existing when it is the step that's creating the table, that seems odd. Have you tried removing the test database explicitly?  Perhaps a previous run has set the `django_migrations` table, so your test runs would think those tables exist and not create them, and then your app code would attempt to access them and fail?

Comment: I don't know exactly what the problem was but I started with a fresh database and the problem went away.